# SQL query to compare the amount

Tags: sql

I have a `Claim` table that holds the claim amount. I need to write a query to compare if the amount is the same or not.

```
SELECT 
    CLAIM_NO, SUM(TRAN_AMOUNT) AS Amount
FROM 
    CLMTABLE
WHERE 
    TRTYPE = 0
GROUP BY 
    CLAIM_NO

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    CLAIM_NO, SUM(TRAN_AMOUNT) AS Amount
FROM 
    CLMTABLE
WHERE 
    TRTYPE <> 0
GROUP BY 
    CLAIM_NO
```

OUTPUT

```
CLAIM_NO   AMOUNT
-----------------
1234567890 883.00
1234567890 883.00
1234567891 990.00
1234567891 990.00
1234567892 883.00
1234567892 893.00
```

The last record the amount is not the same, i want to be able to spot the claim that the amount doesn't match.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query to find all such transaction:

```
SELECT CLAIM_NO,SUM(CASE WHEN TRTYPE=0 THEN ISNULL(TRAN_AMOUNT,0) ELSE 0 END) As Amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRTYPE<>0 THEN ISNULL(TRAN_AMOUNT,0) ELSE 0 END) AS Amount2
FROM CLMTABLE
GROUP BY CLAIM_NO
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TRTYPE=0 THEN ISNULL(TRAN_AMOUNT,0) ELSE 0 END) <> SUM(CASE WHEN TRTYPE<>0 THEN ISNULL(TRAN_AMOUNT,0) ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: @sally: please mark it as a answer if it helped you! So other can benefit from it as well

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE inside a SUM func to retrieve the difference between amount of different types.

```
SELECT claim_no, SUM(CASE WHEN trtype = 0 THEN tran_amount
                     ELSE -1*tran_amount
                     END) as delta
FROM clmtable
GROUP BY claim_no
```

Comment: Thanks,, that is fantastic !